# pimcore debugging

Tags: php, php-5.3, pimcore

Currently I'm using PIMCore for building my website. I've installed it properly on my server with php 5.3.3. I've made all the different pages and everything worked fine till now. I only get white screens when loading the website. The admin-panel however is working fine. I'm quite new to PIMCore and don't really know how to debug this.

What I tried to do:
Enable error_reporting in pimcore/lib/pimcore.php line 216   (nothing)
Put a die('test');  in the pimcore.php file to see where it stops. 
When I put it in the function unsetAdminMode I can see test on my website, when I put it in the function inAdmin, I don't see it.

Is there anybody who can help me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never used pimcore but to force error reporting on you can do the following:

```
error_reporting(-1); // better than E_ALL

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('html_errors', 1); // Pretty errors, even better with xdebug

restore_error_handler();
```

You can also check in your apache_error and php_log log files.

Comment: Thank you! There was allready some error_reporting set, but with this code we see a lot more.

Answer (score 7):

Enable the debug-mode in Settings->System->General, then you'll see all error messages ;-)
http://www.pimcore.org/wiki/display/PIMCORE/System+Settings

Answer (score 2):

In the Admin GUI you can enable debug mode:
**Settings > System > Debug**

The you can tail the debug logs in Pimcore:
**tail -f website/var/log/debug.log**

I usually enable DEV-Mode for my development environment.